# Eclipse autocomplete view became wide and block the whole screen

Tags: java, android, eclipse, autocomplete, editor

I am developing Android app by using eclipse Indigo 3.7.2 with autocomplete function on. I guess I have accidentally pressed some key combinations on my keyboard and make the autocomplete view blocking half of my screen. Can anyone tell me how to reset the view size of it? thanks!

[image]

Comment: With a 24inch screen this is really annoying because it cover a lot of screen size. I tried disable the function and restart eclipse and the still exist. Please explain the reason of down-vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse could be remembering the size of the dialog for content assist UI in the `workspace/.metadata` directory.

Try editing this file: `<workspace_dir>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/dialog_settings.xml`

Look for the section that looks like this:

`<section name="completion_proposal_size">
</section>`

In my workspace there is no special settings here, but perhaps there are some special settings in your workspace.

Comment: Thanks! eclipse will overwrite the setting when it is quitting. Remember to quit eclipse completely before editing the file.